# Lua reports out of bounds differently based on size of a hole in a sequence

Tags: lua

The following code:

```lua
myList = {1, 5, 9, 10}
myList[8] = 8
table.remove(myList,8)
```

Should produce a table with a border at 4, `nil` in keys 5 and 6, and `8` at key 8, then delete the 8. This program works.

However, the following:

```lua
myList = {1, 5, 9, 10}
myList[9] = 8
table.remove(myList,9)
```

does **not** work, saying that the call to `table.remove` is out of bounds!

This is contradictory: `myList[9]` is a non-null entry, and if `table.remove` requires that there are no borders before the given entry, then the border at 4 should have caused the first example to fail too. The only difference is that the gap in the keys is one step wider!

What's happening here and is it something I can correct?

Comment: Rather than join a new community, I have elected to post a comment to you here about a question you have in software-recs.
The Gimp will probably do what you need. It took about 20 minutes to create and save an empty png of 3500x524288 on an i7 5500u with 8gb running W7. It's free and available here: https://www.gimp.org/downloads/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part of a table that is an array (integer indices starting from 1 and ending at the first `nil` value) is the only part for which `table.remove` is valid. The array part cannot contain "holes"; the first "hole" represents the end of the array.

If you give `table.remove` indices that are not in the array part of the table, then you get undefined behavior. Maybe sometimes it will "work", and sometimes it won't. The workaround is to not specify indices outside of the array part of the table.